# Search file for string but skip lines within block

Tags: python, file, lines, skip

I am sure this is a very basic question but I am trying to search a (XML) file for lines containing ".agdb" but I would like to skip any commented lines in the file.

The commenting is done in blocks such as
< !--
Text here
some may contain ".agdb"
...
..
-- >

and I want to also search after the commented lines for the string and then print all the lines containing the string.

Thanks

Comment: perhaps try Beautiful Soup's Comment type: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#comments-and-other-special-strings

Comment: XML comments cannot be nested right? Then you *might* be able to just use a regex. However I believe is just simpler to use an `xml` parser.